# C:\Users\Documents\Android-1\Android\adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android, batch-file, command-line, adb

I was trying to removed bloatware from my HTC OPCv1 device without rooting it. I used [this](https://youtu.be/3VQSjKQkh7U) tutorial to do so.

I downloaded [this](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?q=http%3A%2F%2Fcl.ly%2FdIcS%3F_ga%3D1.88067288.1944582871.1443068918&redir_token=aXOSpmVOI1U04GZMjDajAPGAVGV8MTQ0NjM2NDg3MUAxNDQ2Mjc4NDcx) Android zip and followed the directions which was to drag it to the command prompt to create a path command.

This is the command:

```
C:\Users\LaTonya\Documents\Android-1\Android\adb devices
```

But once I did this I got this error:

```
C:\Users\LaTonya\Documents\Android-1\Android\adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How do I solve this problem? I keep getting the same error. Please help I dont know what I'm doing wrong

I am using Windows 10 operating system

Comment: adb devices will return list of devices when you use CMD like C:\Users\LaTonya\somefolder\androidsdk\platformtools > adb devices

Comment: navigate to android sdk / platform tools folder

Comment: you can locate manually path where your adb.exe exist

Comment: Place quotes around your path like `"C:\Users\LaTonya\Documents\Android-1\Android\adb devices"`; without the quotes, the _space_ in that path makes it to be treated like _two_ items `*\adb` _and_ `devices`...

Answer (score 0):

Set the path of adb into System Variables. You can find adb in "ADT Bundle/sdk/platform-tools" Set the path and restart the cmd and then try again.

Comment: You can also goto the dir where adb.exe is located and do the same thing if you don't wanna set the PATH